# Ember version 1.10.0 installation

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Am using this command "npm install -g ember-cli" to install ember-cli. It installs me version 1.13.x, but I need to install ember version 1.10.0. Is there any command to install it?

Comment: Change it in `bower.json`

Comment: Yeah. Changed it and ran "ember new my-new-app" this command to create sample app called my-new-app. But it is showing "You cannot use the new command inside an ember-cli project."

Comment: You call `ember new` first and then you go into the project it generated, change the `bower.json` entry of that project and run `bower install`. Don't forget `ember-data`. Why would you run `ember new` inside an already generated project...

Comment: Thanks for your time. And one more thing, which version of ember-data should I've to give and what are all the dependancies I've to change in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First delete your `node_modules` and `bower_components` folders. Given your `package.json` and `bower.json` files are correct, run:

```
npm install && bower install
```

if it still does not work, run:

```
npm install ember-cli@1.10.0
```

Also I would suggest you don't install it globally in case you have other projects that require different versions of ember cli.

Comment: Thanks. That helps. But I couldn't find "server" inside my-app.

Comment: What is `server` ?  You need to provide more details if you want a better answer. Posting your package.json and bower.json files would help greatly

Comment: My bower.json file - http://pastebin.com/SFr558my  and  my package.json file - http://pastebin.com/2YxfRGc1. I tried to run ember server but I couldn't find "server" directory in my-app.

Comment: ember-cli versions are not the same thing as ember versions

Comment: @QuantumLicht hey, if I run "npm install ember-cli@1.10.0" am getting error "version not found: ember-cli@1.10.0". any help?

Comment: like @Dhaulagiri, mentionned. the ember and ember-cli versioning are not in sync. At least not until version 1.13. You can look at the https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli to decide what version you need to use. Also consider migrating your app to a newer version because 1.10 is pretty old.